# Android: Scroll in a NestedScrollView to align a View to visible screen top

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I have expandable views in my layout like this.
[image]

Suppose I click on education, I need my `NestedScrollView` to move such that Education `CardView`  should align to visible top of layout/screen.

I tried `scrollView.smoothScrollTo(view.getTop());`
It's as if the function is not even getting called.

Code where I am calling `smoothScrollTo()`

```
@OnClick(R.id.ip_expand_experience)
void expandExperiences(){
    if(!experiencesExpanded){
        AnimationUtils.expand(experiencesCard,context,CARD_HEIGHT_COLLAPSED);
        experiencesExpanded=true;
        focusOnView(experiencesCard);
    }else{
        AnimationUtils.collapse(experiencesCard,context,CARD_HEIGHT_COLLAPSED);
        experiencesExpanded=false;
    }

}

private void focusOnView(final View view){
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view.getTop());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 your_scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            your_scrollview.scrollTo(0, yourview.getBottom());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah. I tried `view.top()` ,`view.bottom`, `view.getTop()-view.getMeasuredHeight()`. That part of code is doing nothing it seems.